# Discord.py delete all messages except pin messages

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

Currently my discord bot has a feature when a person types !delete it deletes most text in the channel. However, it deletes all messages including pinned one. How can I enhance my code so that it does not delete pin messages?

```
if message.content.startswith('!delete'):
   tmp = await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Clearing messages...')
   async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel):
     await client.delete_message(msg)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `purge_from` function and use`check` parameter for only delete non-pinned messages.

dicord.py :

```
if message.content.startswith('!delete'):
    await client.purge_from(channel, limit=None, check=lambda msg: not msg.pinned)
```

discord.py-rewrite:

```
if message.content.startswith('!delete'):
    await channe.purge(limit=None, check=lambda msg: not msg.pinned)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the message is pinned using [`message.pinned`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.pinned).

```
if message.content.startswith('!delete'):
    tmp = await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Clearing messages...')
    async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel):
        if not msg.pinned:
            await client.delete_message(msg)
```